# Cast IPrincipal to IClaimsPrincipal returning null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I have inherited come code (an MVC web app) and am having trouble getting it to start.

These two lines exist:

```
var claimsPrincipal = principal as IClaimsPrincipal;
if (claimsPrincipal == null)
    throw new ArgumentException("Cannot convert principal to IClaimsPrincipal.", "principal");
```

`principal` is an `IPrincipal` (in this case a `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal`), and is not null.

The first line sets `claimsPrincipal` to null, so the exception is thrown.  I'm assuming it must have worked for someone at some point, and this is a fresh copy from source control.  Why would this cast return null for me?

Answer (score 1):

I see that this post is a long time ago. But I encountered the same problem today, and finally I get the way to resolve it.

In framework 4.5 or 4.6, you can directly cast `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal` into `IClaimsPrincipal`, because the first one implements the second one. But in framework 3.5 or 4.0, you cannot do this, becasue the first one doesn't implement the second one.It just implements IPrinciple, not IClaimsPrincipal. You can see it from MSDN link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal(v=vs.100).aspx).

Here it a way to resovle this and get the IClaimsPrincipal object.

```
            var t = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
            WindowsClaimsPrincipal wcp = new WindowsClaimsPrincipal(t);
            IClaimsPrincipal p = wcp as IClaimsPrincipal;
```

HttpContext.Current.User is a WindowsPrincipal, and finally you can get IClaimPrincipal.

Answer (score 0):

`principal` might in fact be `null`. Did you debug that?

Check to see if the type of `principal` implements the `IClaimsPrincipal` interface.

Comment: Ah I beg your pardon.  `principal` is an `IPrincipal` (in this case a `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal`), and is not null.  Question updated.